# How to add hovertool for just one of multiple datasets when plotting using Bokeh

Tags: python, hover, bokeh

I am plotting two datasets using Bokeh in Python. One dataset I am plotting as a line and the other as a marker (circle cross). I am trying to add a hovertool for just the marker dataset.

```py
source = ColumnDataSource(df_bcn_rns)

p = figure(plot_height=300,
           plot_width=800,
           tools="",
           toolbar_location=None,
           x_axis_type='datetime',
           x_axis_location="above",
           background_fill_color="#efefef") #,x_range=(bcn_sp.index[-1], bcn_sp.index[0])

p.line(x=bcn_sp['Date'],
       y=bcn_sp['Close'])
#,source=source)

p.circle_cross(x='Date',
               y='price',
               source=source)

p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Closing Price'


p.add_tools(HoverTool(
        tooltips=[( 'date',   '@Date{%d-%m-%Y}'),
                  ( 'price',  '@price{00.2f}p'), # use @{ } for field names with spaces
                  ( 'rns header', '@Headline')],

        formatters={'Date' : 'datetime', # use 'datetime' formatter for 'date' field
                    'close' : 'printf'},   # use 'printf' formatter for 'adj close' field
        mode='vline' # display a tooltip whenever the cursor is vertically in line with a glyph
    ))

show(column(p)) #,select
```

The code above works, however, the hovertool shows when the mouse is over either dataset. When the mouse is over the line dataset, it shows "???" in the hover box, I don't want it to show anything.

To summarise, the result I was expecting was the hover box showing whenever the mouse is over a marker, but no hover box whenever the mouse is over just the line as this dataset is not linked to "source". Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`markers = p.circle_cross(...)` returns a `markers` renderer that you need to specify as the only renderer for your `HoverTool`. See two possible options how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58365920/only-show-hover-tooltip-for-diamonds-in-python-bokeh/58399794#58399794)